# Affiliation symbol next to author but not in reference format

Tags: acm, acmart

Using [acm](https://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template) template, I'm trying to add multiple authors with different affiliations. My current way of doing it is

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}

\begin{document}

\copyrightyear{2018}
\acmYear{2018}
\setcopyright{rightsretained}
\acmConference[SIGConf '18]{ACM SIG Conf}{2018}{USA}
\acmBooktitle{SIGConf '18: ACM SIG Conf, 2018, USA}
\acmDOI{00.0000/0000000.0000000}
\acmISBN{000-0-0000-0000-0/00/00}


\title[]{Title}

\author{Author 1$^1$, Author 2$^2$, Author 3$^2$, Author 4$^1$, and Author 5$^1$}
\affiliation{\vspace{0.1cm}
\institution{$^1$ Affilation 1}
\institution{$^2$ Affilation 2}
}
\email{{author1, author2, author3, author4, author5}@affilation.com}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
Intro

\end{document}
```

Which will display the following:
[image]

which is fine and what I want. The problem is that the ACM Reference Format will also include the affiliation numbers 
[image]

Is there a way to hide the numbers from the ACM reference format, but keep them in the author section?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you provide a minimal working example instead of just a code snippet -- includes documentclass, the packages you are loading, and `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. I'm assuming you're using `acmart`, but under which format?

Comment: @Troy Updated. I'm using `sigconf`

Comment: Did you find the way how to hide those superscripts?

Answer (score 3):

This is definitely *not* the way ACM wants authors to be entered.  The approved way is:

```
\author{Author 1}
\affiliation{
  \institution{Institution 1}
  \country{Country 1}
}
\author{Author 2}
\affiliation{
  \institution{Institution 2}
  \country{Country 2}
}
```

Comment: With 5 or more authors, it will take a lot of space. I've seen so many papers with inline authors.

Comment: ACM specifically wanted it this way.  You may combine authors with the same affiliation (`\author{...}\author{...}\affiliation{...}`), but the overall design was set by the publisher.

Answer (score 1):

This should works:

```
\author{author one$^{1,2}$, author two$^{1,2}$, author three$^{1,2}$, author four$^3$}
\def \authors{author one, author two, author three, author four}
\affiliation{%
\institution{$^1$Affil one
\country{country}}
}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{$^2$Affil two
  \country{country}}
}
\affiliation{%
\institution{$^3$Affil three
\country{country}}
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No sure if this is what ACM recommends, but I agree it is nice to organize authors in this way. ACM Reference Format is generated from "\authors". You can use following to specify authors in ACM Reference Format by yourself:

```
\renewcommand{\authors}{Author 1, Author 2,...}
```

Comment: This causes the author list in the ACM reference format block to go blank for me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a lot of organizers for ACM conferences don't care about the superscript numbers appearing in the reference format. I've seen a few papers published with those in there.

Space in your paper should go towards the actual discussion. Don't get caught up by ACM's rules. When you are going to end up with more than one line of author blocks, I would just do it the way you are describing.